# angular directive require non parent directive controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive

I wrote [ADM-dateTimePicker](https://github.com/AmirkabirDataMiners/ADM-dateTimePicker) module.
Currently I'm appending datePicker popup to main directive element, and requiring its controller to use it like an api:

```
angular.module('ADM-dateTimePicker', [])
    .directive('admDtp', [function() {
        return {
            require: ['ngModel', 'admDtp'],
            link: function() {},
            controller: [function() {}]
        }
    }])
    .directive('admDtpCalendar', [function() {
        return {
            require: '^^admDtp',
            link: [function() {}]
        }
    }])
```

In case of using `adm-dtp` in some dialogs with hidden overflow, my datePicker will hide too, and sometimes has z-index issue.
I think i have these two options:

- **make popup position fixed**.
  this will solve the problem but i think sticking in screen and not moving with scroll might be annoying for users.
- **append to document body**
  the only problem is i cannot require `^^admDtp`! because `admDtp` is not the parent of popup anymore.

Any idea for solving this issue!?

I'm Ok with appending popup to document body but how can I require non parent directive controller to use its api ?

Comment: If you need two directives to communicate and not rely on directive hierarchy, do this through a service. It is also not clear why the directive should be placed in DOM in a place where it will be visible (body, etc). Just add/remove the elements dynamically to the places you want. You can learn some tricks from existing Angular modal solutions.

Comment: @estus any parent with overflow hidden will affect all nested childs, it might be an angular material dialog, or simple div element! so that's the cause of appending to body root.